# Github API Create a Pull Request always 422 Error

Tags: bash, api, github

i wrote a script to create a github pull request by an api. This is part of a gitflow action to merge a hotfix automatically into the develop. Anyway,..

i always got the error 422 Validation failed, or the endpoint has been spammed.
[Github API Docu](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-pull-request)

i cant handle why and what could be wrong.

You can see my code below. May some of you can see my problem.

```bash
function create_pr()
{
 TITLE="hotfix auto merged by $(jq -r ".pull_request.head.user.login" "$GITHUB_EVENT_PATH" | head -1)."
 REPO_FULLNAME=$(jq -r ".repository.full_name" "$GITHUB_EVENT_PATH")
 RESPONSE_CODE=$(curl -o $OUTPUT_PATH -s -w "%{http_code}\n" \
  --data "{\"title\":\"$TITLE\", \"head\": \"$BASE_BRANCH\", \"base\": \"$TARGET_BRANCH\"}" \
  -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  "https://api.github.com/repos/$REPO_FULLNAME/pulls")
 echo "head: $SOURCE_BRANCH, base: $TARGET_BRANCH"
 echo "Create PR Response:"
 echo "Code : $RESPONSE_CODE"
 if [[ "$RESPONSE_CODE" -ne "201" ]];
 then  
  echo "Could not create PR";
  exit 1;
 else  echo "Created PR";
 fi
}
```

Comment: Does the GitHub token have write permissions?

Comment: Also, you can use `gh`, the GitHub CLI, which is on every runner and lets you create PRs very conveniently.

Comment: yes, the github action got any permissions

Comment: Can you `curl -v`? How do you set the token in the environment?

Comment: Don’t you need to base64 encode the GITHUB_TOKEN in the Auth header? It should not be used as is for this.